# Can't install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have a Class Library named `DataLayer` and wanted to install some nuget packages to it.

I have successfully installed the packages below:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (version 5.0.8)
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` (version 5.0.8)

When I try to install the following package, however:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet` (version 2.0.3)

I get this error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.3' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'DataLayer'.

I've restarted Visual Studio several times and also deleted my Class Library one time, but the error keeps occurring. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the error it's providing isn't relevant? It seems like the package you're attempting to install is only intended to be used with .NET CLI projects, not class libraries?

Comment: So you tell me that I don't need to install it now or what ?

Comment: I guess I'm asking whether it's the right tool for the job? What functionality is it offering you? If it's fundamentally designed for a CLI, what value will it offer in a class library?

Comment: I've just used it before,  today, when I wanted to install it, the visual studio showed me this error, but I don't exactly know what value it will offer !

Comment: Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11521) on github.As `divega` said,`EF Triage: as explained by @smitpatel this error is expected when you try to add a project dotnet CLI tool as if it was a regular package. You just don't use it that way.`

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` needs to be added to your class library by editing the project.
Right-click the project and select `Edit *.csproj` Then, add the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @HosseinDara ```<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />``` replace it the place of my answer. and try it. should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** Package instead of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet**. When I was new to ef core this was suggested by a Tutorial but later I realized **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** works same. Seems like the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet** is an older version and not working for my project version.